# Menú de tipo select dentro de otro

Tags: javascript, html, html5

¿Se puede realizar en JavaScript un menú de tipo Select dentro de otro y permitir tener un submenú dentro?

He intentado esto:

```js
    function funcion() {
        var array = ["veracruz", "puebla", "mexico"];
        var select = document.getElementById("estados");
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.innerHTML = array[i];
            select.appendChild(option);
        }
    }
    funcion();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script defer="" src="list-menu.js" type="text/JavaScript">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="estados">
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No termina de quedar claro qué es lo que estás intentando. Lo que es un `select` dentro de un `select` no puedes tenerlo en HTML... pero puedes simularlo de muchas maneras diferentes dependiendo de qué es lo que tengas en mente (especialmente si vas a usar JavaScript). Trata de [edit] tu pregunta añadiendo más detalles de lo que buscas (quizás un pequeño esquema o un ejemplo gráfico sería de ayuda) y lo que has conseguido hasta ahora. Lee [ask] para más información y consejos. Un saludo.

Comment: gracias, lo tomare en cuenta para la próxima. saludos.

Comment: ¿Por qué para la próxima cuando podemos ayudarte en ésta? No dejes para la próxima pregunta, una respuesta que podrías conseguir hoy ;)

Comment: claro, solo me refería a la forma de realizar la pregunta. gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
   var despliega = false;
            
            function muestra(){
             var div4 = document.getElementById('div4');

             if (!despliega) {

              div4.style.display = "block";
              despliega = true;

             } else {

              div4.style.display = "none";
              despliega = false;
         }
        }
```

```css
      .div1{
         width: 200px;
        }
        .div2{
         position: relative;
        }
        .div2 select{
         width: 100%;
         font-weight: bold;
        }
        .div3{
         position: absolute;
         left: 0;
         right: 0;
         top: 0;
         bottom: 0;
        }
        #div4{
         display: none;
         border: 1px #dadada solid;

        }
        #div4 select{
         display: block;
         width: 200px;
        }
        #div4 select:hover{
         background-color: yellow;
        }
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
  <body>
        <form>
            <div class="div1">
                <div class="div2" onclick="muestra();">
                    <select>
                        <option>
                            opcion 1
                        </option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="div3">
                        <!-- ojo con esto -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="div4">
                    <select>
                        <option>
                            opcion 1.1
                        </option>
                        <option>
                            opcion 1.2
                        </option>
                        <option>
                            opcion 1.3
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
            </body>
</html>
```

Comparto la resolución de mi duda, lo he logrado hacer, con la ayuda del vídeo que comente hace unas horas arriba, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

No puedes, por qué sería un select inválido, según [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45787699/how-do-you-nest-a-select-inside-of-another-select-using-javascript) publicación de la comunidad SO inglesa, solo puedes agruparlos, usando `<optgroup>`

Comment: Podría crear su propio componente sin ningún `select`, sólo con un `input` que cambiaría de valor dependiendo de la opción seleccionada.

Comment: he investigado el <optgroup> se me hizo interesante, sin embargo no es lo que requiero,gracias por el dato.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro a que te refieres podrías darme algún ejemplo ?

Comment: @EduardoUV sería con una lista HTML, dándole formato con CSS y funcionalidad con JavaScript, pero haría falta saber cómo es lo que buscas. Por ejemplo, yo me lo imagino como un menú expandible (como los que se ven en los menús de navegación de algunos sitios), pero no sé si es eso lo que quieres. Deberías editar la pregunta para añadir una descripción de lo que buscas y, a ser posible, un ejemplo de cómo los datos de los múltiples select estarían relacionados.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro lo que busco implementar es eso mismo que me dices como los menus desplegables en algunos sitios con submenus pero utilizando el formato de los <select> con los <options>  y con javascript, ya que cuando seleccione a uno me debe de mostrar otro submenu.. me explico ?... pero primero que nada quiero saber si eso se puede hacer, sino quitarme esa idea y buscar otra forma.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yMKTRn_THeA es como lo que hace este chavo, pero utilizando solo <select>

Answer (score 1):

Sé que esto no es exactamente un `select` como pones en la pregunta, es un pequeño componente HTML que desarrollé y que te genera una especie de menú desplegable y que guarda el valor en un `input` de tipo `hidden`.

Funciona, pero no es ideal porque no parece un control normal de formulario (aunque se podría usar CSS para que pareciese uno, especialmente si estás usando una librería como Bootstrap o similar). Aquí lo puedes ver funcionando:

```js
var lis = document.querySelectorAll(".valor-desplegable [data-val]");
// cada vez que se pulse en una opción del menú desplegable
for (var x = 0; x < lis.length; x++) {
  lis[x].addEventListener("click", function() {
    // actualizar el texto y el valor
    document.getElementById("miValorVisible").textContent = this.textContent;
    document.getElementById("miValor").value = this.dataset.val;
  });
}

// mostrar el valor cuando se pulse en Enviar (en vez de enviar)
document.getElementById("enviar").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("El valor del select es: " + document.getElementById("miValor").value);
});
```

```css
.valor-desplegable {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.valor-desplegable:hover  {
  overflow: visible;
}

.valor-desplegable .valorTexto {
  width: 200px;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #222;
}

.valor-desplegable .valorTexto::after {
  content: "\25BF";
  position: absolute;
  right: 4px;
  color: #222 !important;
}

.valor-desplegable > ul,
.valor-desplegable > ul > li > ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 24px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: white;
}

.valor-desplegable li {
  display: block;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.valor-desplegable li:hover {
  overflow: visible;
  background: #f8f8f8;
}

.valor-desplegable > ul > li > ul {
  top: -1px;
  left: 198px;
}

.valor-desplegable > ul > li > ul::before {
  content:"\25B9";
  position: absolute;
  left: -15px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="valor-desplegable">
    <input type="hidden" name="miValor" id="miValor" value="" />
    <div id="miValorVisible" class="valorTexto">Selecciona un valor</div>
    <ul>
      <li data-val="1">Opción 1</li>
      <li>
        Opción 2
        <ul>
          <li data-val="2.1">Sub-opción 2.1</li>
          <li data-val="2.2">Sub-opción 2.2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        Opción 3
        <ul>
          <li data-val="3.1">Sub-opción 3.1</li>
          <li data-val="3.2">Sub-opción 3.2</li>
          <li data-val="3.3">Sub-opción 3.3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li data-val="4">Opción 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="enviar" />
</form>
```